# CakePHP FormHelper, Creating Login Form In Cell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Inside my cell, which I'm attempting to render in the default template, I have this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Users', ['action'=>'login']);
```

However this renders the following

```
<form method='post' action='/pages/login'>
```

The action in the form is not correct. How do I correctly get the form to point to `Users/login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']]) ?>
```